# How to determine the execution time of a jQuery script?

Tags: jquery, execution-time

I found an interesting script ([link](http://codepen.io/Busuttil-Nicolas/pen/azqEdK)) but it runs only once after the document was loaded, how do I run the script every time I see it? Thanks guys.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    setTimeout(function(){
         $('.trans--grow').addClass('grow');
    }, 275);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'every time I see it'?

Comment: Whit `<body onload="myFunction()">` the script is executed immediately. I want to put this script between two sections and while I scroll the site this animation should animate every time I see this animation between the two sections.
I don't know if I explained well this time.

Comment: Something similar to                                                                             `<div focus="myFunction(275)">
 <hr class="trans--grow hr1">
 <p> Animate the hr , with the use of <strong>jQuery<strong> and <strong>Css3<strong></p>
 <hr class="trans--grow hr2">
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap this code into another function like this:

```
function yourFunction (delayMs) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.trans--grow').addClass('grow')
    }, delayMs)
}
```

And invoke this function whenever you want via `yourFunction(275)`.